# Adafruit CC3000 wifi with HTTPserver.ino

Tags: arduino, wifi

I'm not able to run the server related examples. It remains listening for connections forever. for HTTPserver.ino, Chatserver.ino. the serial monitor gets stuck at this line :

CODE: SELECT ALL | TOGGLE FULL SIZE
Hello, CC3000!

Free RAM: 789

Initializing...

Attempting to connect to Abu Hashem
Connected!
Request DHCP

IP Addr: 192.168.1.11
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
DHCPsrv: 192.168.1.1
DNSserv: 192.168.1.1

NOTE: This sketch may cause problems with other sketches
since the .disconnect() function is never called, so the
AP may refuse connection requests from the CC3000 until a
timeout period passes.  This is normal behaviour since
there isn't an obvious moment to disconnect with a server.

Listening for connections...

When I copy the ip address to my browser it is just unable to load the page. "This site can’t be reached"

Why does such problems occur ? what might be a solution for that ? and how can I chat with the server? I'm a beginner to Arduino (*please be as detailed as you can)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the message because the server at the designated IP address is failing to respond.

The fact that you are able to listen for connections shows the CC3000 is connecting to your router which is good.

Check if Port 80 is assigned for the LISTEN_PORT which by default it should be:

```
#define LISTEN_PORT           80      // What TCP port to listen on for connections.
                                      // The HTTP protocol uses port 80 by default.
```